# While compiling vaadin theme showing the error

Tags: java, vaadin, java-ee-6, vaadin7

While compiling Vaadin theme it is showing the error:

> **select a theme file (.scss) or a vaadin project to compile**
> `@import "addons.scss";
> @import "../ftpcapp/ftpcapp";
> @import "../valo/valo";
> @import "../ftpcapp/custom";
> @import "AppTheme.scss";
> @include variables($background18, $app18, black);
> @include settings($app18, $background18);

```
.ftpcapp18 {
  @include addons;
  @include valo;
  @include themeitems($app18, $button-color18);
  @include ftpcapp;
  @include AppTheme;
  @include custom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `@Theme` annotation theme name matches theme folder name `src/main/VAADIN/themes` and that there is correctly named `.scss` file like in this picture. I assume (based on the error message) you are using IDE plugin instead of maven to compile the theme. So you need to have the folder / theme file selected, when you when clicking the "paint"-icon of the plugin that triggers the theme compilation.

[image]